# KnockoutJS get JSON from remote source with mapping plugin binding issue

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jsonp, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this jQuery:

```
$.ajax({url : sUrl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8" },
    error: function (a, b, c){
        alert(a);
        alert(a.status);
        alert(b);
        alert(c);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        alert(viewModel);

        /*$.each(data, function (index, element) { 
            alert(index);
            alert(element);
        });*/
    }
});
```

the `alert(data);` gives me this:

[image]
The second alert gives me:

```
function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.equalityComparer&&c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0])||(c.K(),d=arguments[0],c.J()),this;a.q.bb(c);return d}
```

The `.each` run until index > 100, so there is a row set returned.

Here is a small piece of my JSON (when I manually hit the url from `var sUrl`:

```
([{    "0":"C551003",
       "id":"57024",
       "1":"0373",
       "number":"373-NIK",
       "2":"1349078013",
       "date_time":"1349078192",
       // etc.
 },{ // next item
```

I just have no clue what the best approach will be to parse this JSON to a nice table. I thought that it would give me an array of rows in the viewmodel and that I could do something like this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html
but I have no idea if the mapping worked and how I can bind to for instance the `number` prop.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: iHaveNoClue">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: 0"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: 1"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: 2"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: date_time"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note up front: because you have properties whose name is a number, you'll have to jump through some hoops to get the `text` bindingHandler to work. One way is to replace `text: 1` with `text: $data['1']`.

---

You are on the right track. The `iHaveNoClue` can be replaced with `$root`, .e.g:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root">
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTXMt/1/) for an example. This works, because the viewModel itself will be made into an `observableArray` by the ko.mapping plugin.

---

**Alternative solution**
Alternatively, you can create a view model that just holds an items observable array with the stuff you get with the AJAX request. Your view model could be constructed like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    title: ko.observable("My title"),
    items: ko.mapping.fromJS(data)
};
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfKJM/2/) for a demo of that version. In this example the viewModel is a simple object, but you could also create a constructor function that builds a more complex view model.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks for your reply. I had `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);` instead of `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` and I forgot to `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`. Your `$root` fixed it! Thanks again, made my day!

Comment: Ow I noticed a small bug. The viewmodel properties like 0,1,2 are not parsed in your jsFiddle. It does not work.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That's a seperate issue altogether though. I've updated my answer and linked fiddles to account for that issue too.